# Python MPI reduce and bcast

Tags: python, mpi, broadcast, reduce, rank

I have a Beowulf cluster with two nodes (master,slave1) and I have to use MPI with Python in this code below. Is an image filter named "Mediana". My question is, in what part of the code can I apply MIP?? I have read a lot of bcast, reduce, send, receive but I don't know where can I use it.

This is my code:

```
enter code here
for w in range(width):
    for h in range(height):
        if w > 0 and w < width-1 and h > 0 and h < height-1:
            r1, g1, b1 = pixeles[w,h]
            r2, g2, b2 = pixeles[w,h-1]
            r3, g3, b3 = pixeles[w-1,h]
            r4, g4, b4 = pixeles[w,h+1]
            r5, g5, b5 = pixeles[w+1,h]
            r, g, b = ((r1+r2+r3+r4+r5)/5,
                       (g1+g2+g3+g4+g5)/5,
                       (b1+b2+b3+b4+b5)/5)
            pixeles[w,h] = (r,g,b)
image.save("/home/jose/Descargas/resultado3.jpg")
print("finish")
```

mediana()

Thanks!

Comment: Easiest thing IMO is to avoid MPI unless you absolutely need it. Since processing a single .jpg file probably takes very little time, I would leave that as a single unit of work, and parallelize the task of processing multiple .jpg files. For an easy python speedup for a single .jpg file, you might consider using cython, or even just straight C.

Comment: Thanks, but is a project and is required to use MPI so I have to

Comment: Here are some examples of using MPI with python I found via google: https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/src/74d8da24a9f412bd546f6cf84dd4f5ebe340aeea/docs/source/usrman/tutorial.rst?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default
Sorry I don't have experience with MPI but the tutorial makes it look so simple! hah

Comment: Here all you need is bcast and reduce to start but that won't be optimal for other uses.

Comment: You can tile the w and h loops and give different processes different tiles to work on. Just remember to give them the boundary pixels they need at each tile.